# the android sdk license dialog in project settings doesn't accept when I click it

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

**Followed this exactly to step 2:**

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Platforms/Android/GettingStarted

When I get to the Accept SDK button, it doesn't accept or grey out. There are a few more people with this issue this month, and I have seen no solutions.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Mobile/Android/InstallingAndroidCodeWorksAndroid

I did this installation process as well.

**Here's the button**

[image]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it didn't work.

I tried other engine versions of unreal and they didn't work.
Issues were with 4.19.2, 4.18 and 4.17.

Comment: try this command for SDK licence `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: c:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools\bin>sdkmanager --licenses
Error: Unknown argument --licenses

Comment: just copy paste this command in your cmd in windows 
`%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`  %ANDROID_HOME% is your android path variable name here you don't need to go in that path

Comment: Tried that; accepted 6 licenses, but the unreal license is still showing up as not accepted

`---------------------------------------
Accept? (y/N): y
All SDK package licenses accepted`

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
Warning: Observed package id 'build-tools;25.0.3' in inconsistent location 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\android-7.1.1' (Expected 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\25.0.3')
Warning: Observed package id 'build-tools;25.0.3' in inconsistent location 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\android-7.1.1' (Expected 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\25.0.3')
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unreal isn't clear in specifying that you need to locate the folder that contains the files, not just C:\NVPACK. Should be something like C:\NVPACK\Android-sdk-windows

Answer (score 1):

You may need to manually identify the location of the SDK, NDK and JRE folders, as it was for me. Edit > Project Settings > Android SDK (near the bottom). After choosing their locations, the license button greyed-out and I was finally able to package for Android. I read, but ignored the page in the Unreal documentation that instructs you to do so: 
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Mobile/Android/Setup/AndroidStudio/index.html (Manually Targeting SDK Paths is the name of the section).

Answer (score 0):

Type "SDK" in the search area. You'll see Android SDK, which in my case I had not clicked the "accept license" button". This resolved it (I had already pointed to the correct folder as previously recommended).

Answer (score 0):

"Unreal isn't clear in specifying that you need to locate the folder that contains the files, not just C:\NVPACK. Should be something like C:\NVPACK\Android-sdk-windows"

I confirm what PaulEckhardt said.
Pointing subforders inside C:\NVPACK works for me.

Settings that blank do not work. (U4 don't car about my environnement varaibles...)